# processes that run during new user creation

Tags: useradd

I have two questions:

1. What processes typically run when a new user is created?
2. What processes run when an existing (regular) user escalates his privileges to gain root-access?

I Googled a lot and could not find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

useradd is the process that is run when you execute the compiled [useradd](https://fossies.org/dox/shadow-4.2.1/useradd_8c_source.html) (non-official).

As for the second question, Privilege escalation is when someone exploits a vulnerability to gain more rights in the operating system. For example if you find a bug like buffer overflow in a service run by root.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, 'useradd' is a command to add a new user. Under the hood, it has to do several things. For example, PAM would run (for authenticating, resources etc)...which might also spawn one or more process. Not sure.